Displaying seconds accurately with datetime2
I'm using datetime2 under xelatex. Is there any way to get it to display the time in the format hh:mm:ss with an accurate value for the seconds? Currently, the output for seconds is always "00".

Try to load texosquery before datetime2 and enable -shell-escape; As, according to the documentation (page 6), the seconds and time zone are omitted when using XeLaTeX.

Thank you very much. I assume there's no way around loading this additional package? (I'm trying to keep the number of loaded packages small).

As far as I know, this is the only solution, unless you switch to pdfLaTeX or, even better, LuaLaTeX.

If you know which OS this is going to be used on and you are willing to use -shell-escape then you can use a system command in a pipe without any packages at all, for example in Linux \documentclass{article} \begin{document} \makeatletter \input{|"date '+\@percentchar T'"} \makeatother \end{document} which shows the seconds in XeLaTeX.
